# php how to open new tab or new window

Tags: javascript

in php

my task here is before user downloads a file i have display a form thr where i can get details of user i.e form1...on click on submit button it will go to next php file where it process some logic...from thr i have open new tab or new window in that i have display my file or any thing ....how to do

thank u

Comment: This isn't something you can do in PHP, must be done with JavaScript. I have retagged this so it will get the right attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add:

```
onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com/','mywindow','width=400,height=350')"
```

To any Anchor  or Input  tag, or just add this to the head of a file to open automatically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.open('http://www.google.com/','mywindow','width=400,height=350');
</script>
```

^_^ !